# Best practice for consecutive logger calls in multithreaded environment

Tags: multithreading, logging, conventions

Consider this code:

```
if (param1 == null || param2 == null) {
  logger.error("Failed to do stuff.");
  logger.debug("param1: " + param1);
  logger.debug("param2: " + param2);
}
```

It is very readable, but in a multithreaded environment the logically atomic log message could be split into three parts.

Now, part of the solution is simple, and readability does not suffer too much:

```
if (param1 == null || param2 == null) {
  logger.error("Failed to do stuff.");
  logger.debug(
    "param1: " + param1 + System.getProperty("line.separator") 
    + "param2: " + param2
  );
}
```

If slightly changing the logger output is OK, you can write:

```
if (param1 == null || param2 == null) {
  String message = "Failed to do stuff.";

  if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
    message += System.getProperty("line.separator")
      + "param1: " + param1 + System.getProperty("line.separator") 
      + "param2: " + param2;
  }

  logger.error(message);
}
```

Clean log, but uglier code...

Alternatively, you could write:

```
if (param1 == null || param2 == null) {
  synchronized (logger) {
    logger.error("Failed to do stuff.");
    logger.debug("param1: " + param1);
    logger.debug("param2: " + param2);
  }
}
```

What do you recommend and why?

Comment: Which logging library are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Configure the logging subsystem to identify the *logging thread* in its output:

```
timestamp process.thread_id severity Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                  ^^^^^^^^^
```

Now it is easy to thread the log together.

Answer (score 0):

Design a 'LogEntry' class that can hold log text - append entries etc.

Add logger instance calls that:

1) Return a 'LogEntry' class instance in a thread-safe manner, eg. 'LogEntry* GetLogEntry();'.

2) Submit a 'LogEntry' class instance in a thread-safe manner, eg. 'void SubmitLogEntry(LogEntry* thisLog);

SubmitLogEntry() should queue the passed LogEntry* to the logger thread - the one thread that does the actual log writing.